# Изменить подсказку меток с "например, [python с массивы]", чтобы это не выглядело как одна метка

Tags: дефект, локализация

При создании вопроса или если очистить поле меток в подсказке пишет текст "например, [python с массивы]":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видимо, имелись в виду три отдельные метки: python, c, массивы (c как язык программирования)

**Я тут вижу две проблемы:**

- из-за квадратных скобок выглядит как одна метка
- "с" читается как предлог, а не метка языка Си (получается кривое "python с массивами")

На enSO подсказка выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вариант, предлагаю убрать квадратные скобки и разделить названия меток запятыми (и запятая и пробел при вводе завершают метку, при этом запятая естественно выглядит при перечислении отдельных сущностей):

> `например: python, c, массивы`

Или вариант через пробел, но метку "с" заменить на что-то другое. Можно использовать метки как на enSO (но с двоеточием и без круглых скобок):

> `например: typescript sql iphone`

Comment: Скорее всего примут изменения только квадратных скобок на круглые :) В английской версии просто нет запятых, потому так думаю

Comment: А зачем запятые? Метки же через пробел вводятся, а не через запятую.

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что без запятых "python с массивы", читается как кривое "python с массивами") Ну или другие метки как пример указать, чтобы "с" не казался предлогом. Технически и пробел и запятая завершает ввод метки, мне кажется естественнее будет, если перечисление меток будет через запятую.

Comment: @EzioMercer какую версию примем, тот вариант и будет. Я вообще не вижу смысла в скобках там.

Comment: @insolor Тогдя я за вариант с запятыми! Кстати, чтобы не плодить комметарии предлагаю вам написать 2 тега, чтобы мы просто поставили на них плюсики, будет что-то типа голосования

Comment: @insolor Кстати, такой вопрос: А эти метки захордкожены? Или меняются в зависимости от чего-то, например от того на каком ресурсе каких вопросов больше и берётся первые 3? Может потому разные теги в enSO и ruSO?

Comment: @EzioMercer похоже, что нет, как-то сами выбираются: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/10388 . Так что с разделителями не понятно, получится ли легко исправить.